# Extracting data from a URL result with special formatting

Tags: python, parsing, url

I have a URL:
http://somewhere.com/relatedqueries?limit=2&query=seedterm

where modifying the inputs, limit and query, will generate wanted data. Limit is the max number of term possible and query is the seed term.

The URL provides text result formatted in this way:
oo.visualization.Query.setResponse({version:'0.5',reqId:'0',status:'ok',sig:'1303596067112929220',table:{cols:[{id:'score',label:'Score',type:'number',pattern:'#,##0.###'},{id:'query',label:'Query',type:'string',pattern:''}],rows:[{c:[{v:0.9894380670262618,f:'0.99'},{v:'newterm1'}]},{c:[{v:0.9894380670262618,f:'0.99'},{v:'newterm2'}]}],p:{'totalResultsCount':'7727'}}});

I'd like to write a python script that takes two arguments (limit number and the query seed), go fetch the data online, parse the result and return a list with the new terms ['newterm1','newterm2'] in this case.

I'd love some help, especially with the URL fetching since I have never done this before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you can break this problem up into several subproblems.

## Subproblems

There are a handful of problems that need to be solved before composing the completed script:

1. **Forming the request URL:** Creating a configured request URL from a template
2. **Retrieving data:** Actually making the request
3. **Unwrapping [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP):** The returned data appears to be [JSON](http://json.org/) wrapped in a JavaScript function call
4. **Traversing the object graph:** Navigating through the result to find the desired bits of information

### Forming the request URL

This is just simple string formatting.

```
url_template = 'http://somewhere.com/relatedqueries?limit={limit}&query={seedterm}'
url = url_template.format(limit=2, seedterm='seedterm')
```

> #### Python 2 Note
>
> You will need to use the string formatting operator (`%`) here.
>
> ```
> url_template = 'http://somewhere.com/relatedqueries?limit=%(limit)d&query=%(seedterm)s'
> url = url_template % dict(limit=2, seedterm='seedterm')
> ```

### Retrieving data

You can use the built-in urllib.request module for this.

```
import urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # url from previous section
```

This returns a file-like object called `data`. You can also use a with-statement here:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as data:
    # do processing here
```

> #### Python 2 Note
>
> Import `urllib2` instead of `urllib.request`.

### Unwrapping JSONP

The result you pasted looks like JSONP. Given that the wrapping function that is called (`oo.visualization.Query.setResponse`) doesn't change, we can simply strip this method call out.

```
result = data.read()

prefix = 'oo.visualization.Query.setResponse('
suffix = ');'

if result.startswith(prefix) and result.endswith(suffix):
    result = result[len(prefix):-len(suffix)]
```

### Parsing JSON

The resulting `result` string is just JSON data. Parse it with the built-in json module.

```
import json

result_object = json.loads(result)
```

### Traversing the object graph

Now, you have a `result_object` that represents the JSON response. The object itself be a `dict` with keys like `version`, `reqId`, and so on. Based on your question, here is what you would need to do to create your list.

```
# Get the rows in the table, then get the second column's value for
# each row
terms = [row['c'][2]['v'] for row in result_object['table']['rows']]
```

## Putting it all together

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""A script for retrieving and parsing results from requests to
somewhere.com.

This script works as either a standalone script or as a library. To use
it as a standalone script, run it as `python3 scriptname.py`. To use it
as a library, use the `retrieve_terms` function."""

import urllib.request
import json
import sys

E_OPERATION_ERROR = 1
E_INVALID_PARAMS = 2

def parse_result(result):
    """Parse a JSONP result string and return a list of terms"""
    prefix = 'oo.visualization.Query.setResponse('
    suffix = ');'

    # Strip JSONP function wrapper
    if result.startswith(prefix) and result.endswith(suffix):
        result = result[len(prefix):-len(suffix)]

    # Deserialize JSON to Python objects
    result_object = json.loads(result)

    # Get the rows in the table, then get the second column's value
    # for each row
    return [row['c'][2]['v'] for row in result_object['table']['rows']]

def retrieve_terms(limit, seedterm):
    """Retrieves and parses data and returns a list of terms"""
    url_template = 'http://somewhere.com/relatedqueries?limit={limit}&query={seedterm}'
    url = url_template.format(limit=limit, seedterm=seedterm)

    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as data:
            data = perform_request(limit, seedterm)
            result = data.read()
    except:
        print('Could not request data from server', file=sys.stderr)
        exit(E_OPERATION_ERROR)

    terms = parse_result(result)
    print(terms)

def main(limit, seedterm):
    """Retrieves and parses data and prints each term to standard output"""
    terms = retrieve_terms(limit, seedterm)
    for term in terms:
        print(term)

if __name__ == '__main__'
    try:
        limit = int(sys.argv[1])
        seedterm = sys.argv[2]
    except:
        error_message = '''{} limit seedterm

limit must be an integer'''.format(sys.argv[0])
        print(error_message, file=sys.stderr)
        exit(2)

    exit(main(limit, seedterm))
```

### Python 2.7 version

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

"""A script for retrieving and parsing results from requests to
somewhere.com.

This script works as either a standalone script or as a library. To use
it as a standalone script, run it as `python2.7 scriptname.py`. To use it
as a library, use the `retrieve_terms` function."""

import urllib2
import json
import sys

E_OPERATION_ERROR = 1
E_INVALID_PARAMS = 2

def parse_result(result):
    """Parse a JSONP result string and return a list of terms"""
    prefix = 'oo.visualization.Query.setResponse('
    suffix = ');'

    # Strip JSONP function wrapper
    if result.startswith(prefix) and result.endswith(suffix):
        result = result[len(prefix):-len(suffix)]

    # Deserialize JSON to Python objects
    result_object = json.loads(result)

    # Get the rows in the table, then get the second column's value
    # for each row
    return [row['c'][2]['v'] for row in result_object['table']['rows']]

def retrieve_terms(limit, seedterm):
    """Retrieves and parses data and returns a list of terms"""
    url_template = 'http://somewhere.com/relatedqueries?limit=%(limit)d&query=%(seedterm)s'
    url = url_template % dict(limit=2, seedterm='seedterm')

    try:
        with urllib2.urlopen(url) as data:
            data = perform_request(limit, seedterm)
            result = data.read()
    except:
        sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % 'Could not request data from server')
        exit(E_OPERATION_ERROR)

    terms = parse_result(result)
    print terms

def main(limit, seedterm):
    """Retrieves and parses data and prints each term to standard output"""
    terms = retrieve_terms(limit, seedterm)
    for term in terms:
        print term

if __name__ == '__main__'
    try:
        limit = int(sys.argv[1])
        seedterm = sys.argv[2]
    except:
        error_message = '''{} limit seedterm

limit must be an integer'''.format(sys.argv[0])
        sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % error_message)
        exit(2)

    exit(main(limit, seedterm))
```

Comment: Anyway to make that script work in 2.7? Also I think it needs '__main__':

Comment: This script was written to work with Python 3. I'll add notes to the answer for how to use it on Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

i didn't understand well your problem because from your code there it seem to me that you use [Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#Query) (it's the first time that i hear about it by the way).

But well if you are just searching for a way to fetch data from a web page you could use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) this is just for getting data, and if you want to parse the retrieved data  you will have to use a more appropriate library like [BeautifulSoop](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

if you are dealing with another web service (RSS, Atom, RPC) rather than web pages you can find a bunch of python library that you can use and that deal with each service perfectly.

```
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

result =  urllib2.urlopen('http://somewhere.com/relatedqueries?limit=%s&query=%s' % (2, 'seedterm'))

htmletxt = resul.read()

result.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, convertEntities="html" )

# you can parse your data now check BeautifulSoup API.
```